# How to write an NFC tag with Driving Directions?

Tags: google-maps, nfc, google-maps-navigation

I want to write an NFC Tag on a sticker with something that will directly open Google Maps driving directions to a specific address. I've tried using "NFC Tasks" / "NFC Tools", but haven't found any preset that seems to fit the bill. These come close:

- "**Address**: Open an address"; and
- "**Geolocation**: Open an geolocation".

But obviously those tasks don't open *driving directions*.

To clarify, on my Nexus 5 with Android 6.0 (but also on 5.x if I remember correctly) I have the option to include a Maps widget on my home screens that do exactly this. When adding such a widget I get this settings screen:

[image: widget settings for driving directions]

Clicking this widget does what it says on the tin: fires off driving directions.

With NFC Tasks you can write URLs, so I tried writing:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=some+address+here
```

But that opens Google Maps *in a browser*, not the Maps application itself.

With NFC Tasks you can also write custom data, but I wouldn't know how to format my custom data for this specific task. The "Pro" version of the tool can write "Send Intent" tasks to tags, but I can't figure out if that's what I need (before I go out and buy the pro version).

I've gone through the suggested duplicates and similar questions, but found no relevant info.

Bottom line: **How do you write Driving Directions to a specific location onto an NFC tag**?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to create a link to a Google maps' destination which automatically detects user's location and triggers the driving directions. You can find how to do it [here](https://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/), in particular see the voice 'Directions (detect user's current location as starting point)'. You just have to write this link on your tag NFC, with any app that provides the possibility (like NFC Tools). The problem may be the storage capacity of your tags: this kind of link is bound to require a lot of bytes. You can choose the bigger size of tags, which cost more, but be sure the link fits, or you can use a provider of shorten link (which I suggest).

Edit: I didn't see you already tried something similar. With mobile browsers, like chrome, if you open a link that points to google maps you should be redirected to the app. Maybe you set your browser to open this kind of links by default instead of the app?